# Is there any problem with "use diagnostics;"?

Tags: perl

With perl I almost always use:

```
use strict;
use diagnostics;
```

I suggested "use diagnostics" instead of `use warnings;` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395999/which-safety-net-do-you-use/6396191#6396191) and I received some negative feedback. So, now I'm thinking:

Is there any problem with  `use diagnostics;`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`diagnostics` isn't a lexical pragma like `warnings`. Instead it sets the global `$^W` variable (like using the `-w` flag), which enables warnings for *all* code, whether it wants it or not, and whether you wrote it or not. That's kind of rude. `diagnostics` is also silly to use in production. I would recommend using `warnings` and then just piping your warnings to `splain` if you need an explanation.

Answer (score 9):

`use diagnostics` will slow down the execution of your code more than `use warnings`.  It's fine to switch it on if you're getting a warning that you don't understand during development, but it's best to switch it off when you're done.

Comment: +1 Better still, though, to write code that doesn't emit warnings and/or diagnostics to begin with. ;-)

Answer (score 8):

The diagnostics pragma is a development tool, and one that you don't need often. Use it on an as-needed basis:

```
$ perl -Mdiagnostics myprog
```

Enabling the pragma with the command-line [`-M` switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#%2a-m%2a%5b%2a-%2a%5d_module_) means you don't have to remember to go back and remove a test-only `use diagnostics` line from your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not yet upgraded to perl version 5.12, **diagnostics** has a bug which masks a specific warning.  The bug has been fixed in 5.12 (see [perl512delta](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5120delta.html#Modules-and-Pragmata)):

> diagnostics no longer suppresses Use
>   of uninitialized value in range (or
>   flip) warnings. [perl #71204]

Once I became aware of the bug, I went back and commented `use diagnostics;` out of all my code.  If I get warning messages, I uncomment it temporarily, but always go back and comment it out again.