# What mistake am I making in this Perl code?

Tags: perl, hash

I tried this code. This isn't working. I am getting no result at output. What mistake am I making?

```
my %fruit_color = ("apple", "red", "banana", "yellow");
my @fruits = keys %fruit_colors;
my @colors = values %fruit_colors;
print @fruits;
print @colors;
```

Codepad link: http://codepad.org/vDVAxJcp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395999/which-safety-net-do-you-use-in-perl/6396191

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're declaring `fruit_color` but referencing `fruit_colors` (notice the trailing S)

You would have noticed this had you used warnings and stricture.

```
use warnings;
use strict;


Global symbol "%fruit_colors" requires explicit package name at C:\temp\test.pl line 4.
Global symbol "%fruit_colors" requires explicit package name at C:\temp\test.pl line 5.
```

Answer (score 7):

The first mistake is not having this as the first lines:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Second, you have a typo ( which would have been easier to spot if you had been using the strict module ).

Answer (score 4):

Man, you people are quick.

As others have stated:

- You created a list with one name, but then referenced it to another.
- If you used `use warnings` and `use strict`, you would have gotten an error message telling you about the error.

There are lots of hints and tricks to writing legible and relatively bug free Perl code. For example, I don't use plurals in variable names. Thus, if it's a question of "fruit" or "fruits", I know it should be "fruit". I also tend to say the name of my data types by using terms like "fruitColorHash" vs. "FruitColorList" even though (Camel Casing isNotInStyleAnyMore, but then Im_an_old_grouchy_developer_who_is_set_in_his_ways).

Damian Conway's book [Perl Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735) is an excellent book that will help you learn all of those tricks and tips that will help you avoid issues like this. In fact, the book is considered such a touchstone of good Perl programming, that there's now an entire section devoted to Damian Conway's book called [Perlstyle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html), and a program called [tidyperl](http://perltidy.sourceforge.net/) that will help reformat and point out places that don't follow Conway's examples.

So, go ahead and look at the Best Practices section in Perldoc (You know about the `perldoc` documentation, don't you? Type in the command `perldoc` and see what you get) and absorb the knowledge placed there in. Then get Conway's book.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo in your code, which you would have noticed if you had had:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
```

in your code. Which you always should.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
my %fruit_color = ("apple", "red", "banana", "yellow");
```

should be

```
my %fruit_colors =  ("apple", "red", "banana", "yellow");
```