# New to perl... having problems with chomp

Tags: perl

I am trying to learn perl programming and am using it to read a file from a contest;

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use warnings;

open(FILE, <~/source/test.txt>);
@array = <FILE>;
$number = shift @array;

while($number--) {
    chomp($key = shift @array);
    chomp($message = shift @array);

    print "Key: $key";
    print "Message: $message";
}
print "\n";
close(FILE);
```

The file contains a number, N, then there are 2 * N lines that follow which is how many key/message pair's there are.

But when I do this program, it only prints out the last "message" and nothing else... it doesn't print anything else. If I remove the chomps it works as intended, but with the chomps there it just cuts everything off... any ideas why?

//EDIT: removed the -w

Comment: your first line should be number of lines in the file and each key and message must be in a new line

Comment: You should use strict. [Why use strict and warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8023959/725418)

Comment: The `-w` is more or less redundant with `use warnings;`.  `-w` enables warnings for any modules as well, which is considered a bad idea these days (since some older modules might not work properly with warnings enabled).  Suggestion: Use `use stricts; use warnings;` and drop the `-w`.

Comment: @run, I didn't create the contest... that's the way they describe it, first line is the number of key/message pairs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are reading a DOS/Win text file on a unix box. Using `chomp`, you are removing the "LF" of "CRLF", but leaving the "CR", causing all your lines to be shown one atop the other.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
use strict;   # Do use this!
use warnings;

open(my $fh, '<', "$ENV{HOME}/source/test.txt") or die $!;
my @array = <$fh>;
s/\s+\z// for @array;  # Universal chomp

my $number = shift(@array);
while ($number--) {
   my $key     = shift(@array);
   my $message = shift(@array);

   print "Key: $key\n";
   print "Message: $message\n";
}
```

Comment: `s/\s+\z//` also removes trailing blanks and tabs, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @Keith Thompson, Indeed, but if you have to deal with a format that relies on meaningful trailing whitespace, I pity you.

Comment: So I should use `my`. I keep looking for tutorials and some reference `my` and some don't for variables... can anyone point me to a decent, recent perl tutorial?

Comment: @Nicholas, `my` creates varaibles with a limited scope. Limiting the scope of variables is a basic Computer Science tenet, so I don't know of any tutorial that covers that specifically. You should be using `use strict;` to have Perl tell you when you forgot to declare (or mispelled) a variable (and a couple of other super useful checks).

Comment: @Nicholas : For Perl tutorials you might begin here: [tutorials](http://perl-tutorial.org/)

Comment: @ikegami, I know about scope. Just the tutorials I was reading were all over the place, with some advocating `my` and some not using it. I should have researched it more in depth I guess. thanks for the advice

Comment: @Nicholas, I don't know who you saw not using it, but try not using their tutorials :)