# Perl. How to edit yaml file?

Tags: perl, yaml, dump

I have a yaml file which looks like this:

```
---
date: 25-01-2010
version: 0.1
```

I want to edit it. I using this code:

```
use YAML::XS qw(LoadFile);
use YAML::Syck qw(Dump);    

my $list = LoadFile("config.yaml");
$list{date} = "12-11-2011";
print "The date is $list->{date} \n";
print "The version is $list->{version} \n";
open F, '>', "config.yaml";
print F Dump( \%list );
close F;
}
```

and when it's done my yaml file contains only date and empty line in the end.

```
--- 
date: 12-11-2011
```

What's wrong with this code? if I checking value version before writing I getting good result, it's showing version but it doesn't write it at all...

I tried to use YAML::Syck::DumbFile but file after writing wasnt contain version too, and it was look like this :

```
---
date:
12-11-2011
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are loading the YAML into `$list`.  Then, you are setting `'date'` in the hash `%list` (a completely different variable, which is initialized empty), and dumping that.

```
${$list}{date} = '12-11-2011';
print Dump($list);
```

You should read [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and

## `use strict;`

Comment: Shame that you can't shout louder in Markdown.

Comment: [Why use strict and warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)