# What does this mean in perl $variable_one{$variable_two} and what is it called?

Tags: perl, scalar

I saw this in a piece of code:

```
if (some_condition) {  
 $index++;  
}  
$index{$some_variable} = $index{$some_variable} + 1;
```

What does `$index{$some_variable}` mean? And why is it used?

Thank you.

EDIT:
index is defined as `$index=0;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's retrieving an entry in the `%index` hash using a key whose value is the value of `$some_variable`

(Note: There may also exist a scalar named `$index` but it will occupy a separate namespace. That is, you can have both a hash and a scalar named `index` and they will not conflict.)

Comment: but index is defined like $index = 0;

Comment: But there will be a `%index` assignment also, `$index` is a scalar, `%index` is a hash, and they're two different variables. When accessing a entry in the hash that is scalar, you use `$index{$myentry}`.

Answer (score 10):

If this code is written correctly, you will have these lines above it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $index;
my %index;

if (some_condition) {  
    $index++;  
}  
$index{$some_variable} = $index{$some_variable} + 1;
```

`$index{$some_variable}` is referring to a hash, and `$index` to a scalar. In perl, this is perfectly valid, and `%index` and `$index` will be considered two different variables.

This is also a reason why it is so important to use strict. [Why use strict and warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)

Comment: It's also the reason why naming variables correctly is important for readability. `%index` should have been named `%indices` or something more meaningful.

Comment: @DVK : I'm not too sure about the plural form. All too often I find myself writing stuff like `for my $lookup ( keys %indices ) { ... say $indices{$lookup}; }` and wondering whether it would be better to stick with `%index` instead.

Comment: @Zaid: then just go the Japanese way and use `index_group` or sth :) (Japanese doesn't have true plurals, many times "plurals" are formed by adding "tachi" (group) to a word.)

Comment: @DVK For what it's worth, Damian (PBP) suggests hashes be named in the singular since it is one element  that is normally accessed at a time.

Comment: @DVK Exactly. If the author had been naming variables appropriately, this question would never have been asked. Case in point.

Comment: @Zaid, In my opinion, hashes that contains a collection should be plural (%fields), and hashes that represent one object (%record) should be singular

Comment: @ikegami - brilliant summation. That should go into every style guide/best practices.

Answer (score 6):

Perl has several namespaces

- `$var` is a scalar variable
- `@var` is an array variable, and `$var[$i]` is an element of that array.
- `%var` is a hash variable, and `$var{$i}` is an element of that hash.

Answer (score 5):

The `$index` in the `$index++;` statement is a scalar. It has nothing to do with the `$index{$some_variable}` statement that follows it.

The `$index{$some_variable}` is part of a hash, `%index`. Hashes (or associative arrays) consist one or more pairs, each pair consisting of a key and a value. The key is used to access the value.:

```
my %hash = ( key_A => value_A,    # Here $hash{key_A} accesses 'value_A'
             key_B => value_B,    # ... $hash{key_B} gives 'value_B'
             key_Z => value_Z  ); # 'value_Z' returned by $hash{key_Z}
```

Analyzing `$index{$some_variable} = $index{$some_variable} + 1;`, the value of `$index{$some_variable}` is accessed, incremented by one and reassigned to the same key.

See [`perldoc perlintro`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types) for a gentle introduction to variable types in Perl, and [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) for more complex data structures.

Answer (score 2):

You might find [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Variable-names) helpful.