# Storing regex result in a new variable

Tags: regex, perl

The below program is to rearrange a string. For line 8, I am trying to store the results of a regex into a new variable $newdate, but when $newdate is printed in line 9, it only displays a 1. How can I change my code so that $newdate will store the $date value from the regex operation?

```
1 #!/usr/bin/perl
2 
3 # This program changes the date format from mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy,mm,dd
4 
5 $date = '21/11/2011';
6 print "Current: $date\n";
7
8 $newdate = $date =~ s/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/$3,$2,$1/;
9 print "New: $newdate\n";
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could also do it like this :

```
my $date = '21/11/2011';
print "Current: $date\n";
my $newdate;
($newdate = $date) =~ s/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/$3,$2,$1/;
print $newdate;
```

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was after.

Answer (score 13):

Since Perl 5.13.2, non-destructive substitution can be specified through the `s///r` modifier so a copy of the post-substitution string is assigned instead of the number of matches. It also prevents the original string from being modified, which means the two assignments have the same behavior:

```
( my $new_date = $date ) =~ s<(..)/(..)/(....)><$3,$2,$1>; # Pre-5.13.2

  my $new_date = $date =~ s<(..)/(..)/(....)><$3,$2,$1>r;  # Post-5.13.2
```

---

From [`perldoc perl5132delta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5132delta.html#Non-destructive-substitution):

> *Non-destructive substitution*
>
> The substitution operator now supports a `/r` option that copies the
>   input variable, carries out the substitution on the copy and returns
>   the result. The original remains unmodified.
>
> ```
> my $old = 'cat';
> my $new = $old =~ s/cat/dog/r;
> # $old is 'cat' and $new is 'dog'
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The `=~` operator will return the number of changes made when doing substitution, and unless you're doing it globally, it will always return 1 or 0. Additionally, the substitutions are made in place, so if your aim is not to modify `$date`, you don't want to substitute.

Try:

```
$date =~ m/(..)\/(..)\/(....)/;
$newdate = "$3,$2,$1";
```

Answer (score 1):

In the spirit of TIMTOWTDI:

```
my $date = '21/11/2011';

my $newdate = join ",", reverse split m#/#, $date;
```

This just happens to work because you want the reverse order on the numbers. You could also do this:

```
my $newdate = join ",", ( split m#/#, $date )[2,1,0];
```

Yet another way:

```
my $newdate = join ",", reverse ( $date =~ /(\d+)/g );
```

Also: [Why use strict and warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)