# How can I process a file two lines at a time in Perl?

Tags: perl, file

I have a signal file with each line beginning with 0 or 1.

If I have 1 followed by 0 in the next line, then I need to process the 0 signal line.

```
>#Sample File

>0

>0

>1

>0 (process line)

>0

>1

>0 (process line)
```

my code

```
 OUTER : while (<F>) {
   if($_=~/1/){
     my $a = <F>
     process_line($a) if ($a=~/0/);
     next OUTER if ($a=~/1/);
   }
```

The file is huge, so I don't want to slurp.

Comment: What is the problem with your existing code ?

Comment: Is there more data on each line? Could the extra data contain 0's and 1's too? If so, then your regex needs to be anchored to the start of the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
my $prevLine = "";

sub processline {
    my $line = shift;
    $line =~ s@^0 @@;
    print $line;
}

while (<DATA>) {
    if ($_ =~ /^0/ && $prevline =~ /^1/) {
        processline($_);
    }
    $prevLine = $_;
}

__DATA__
0
0
1
0 (process line)
0
1
0 (process line)
```

**Output**

```
(process line)
(process line)
```

Comment: Corrected the regexp, for/while and var case parts. Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

I see the possible error with your code: Two or more consecutive lines starting with 1 will misfire and skip a match.

```
while (<>) {
   if(/^1/){            # Ignore everything except 1-lines
      while (<>) {      # Start inner loop
         next if /^1/;  # Skipping consecutive 1-lines
         die "Bad line: $_" unless /^0/;  # Anything not 1 or 0 is not allowed
         process_line($_);
         last;          # Exit inner loop, search for next 1-line
      }
   }
}
```

**Usage options:**

```
script.pl filename        (single file)
script.pl filename*       (glob, multiple files)
some_command | script.pl
```

**Changes:**

- Global filehandle changed to diamond operator, works on STDIN or
  filename arguments to the script. If you want an explicit open, use
  `open my $fh, '<', $filename or die $!`
- Added anchors in the regexes to match beginning of string only, e.g. 
  `/^1/`
- Removed unnecessary label `OUTER`. `next` and `last` will affect the innermost loop only (see [perldoc -f last](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html)).
- `$_ =~ /^1/` changed to `/^1/`, which is equivalent, and more
  legible.
- Nested use of `$_` is valid, and will work as expected. If you
  want, the inner loop can use another variable, e.g. `while (my $line = <>)`, which may be seem less confusing to some. (Not to me, though)

You should use strict and warnings, if you are not already doing so. [Why use strict and warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8023959/725418)

Answer (score 0):

Another variation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
sub processme {
    my $line = shift;
    print $line;
}
while (<>) {
    if (/^1/../^0/) {
        processme( $_ ) if /^0/;
    }
}
```