# Perl code using a text file

Tags: linux, perl, command

Why is my perl code not printing out anything? I have been working on this for a while now and i am using a text file which has a ton of different data which each on of my arrays are sepearated by a comma meaning it is a column.

this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open (FILE, 'census2008.txt');

my @SumLevArray;
my @StNameArray;
my @CtyNameArray;
my @PopEstimateArary;
my @BirthsArray;
my @DeathsArray;

$i = 0;
$temp = 0;
$lowestBirthRates = 100000000;
$highestBirthRates = 0;
$size = 0;


while (<FILE>)
{
chomp;
($sumlev, $stname,$ctyname,$popestimate2008,$births2008,$deaths2008) = split(",");
push (@SumLevArray, $sumlev);
push (@StNameArray, $stname);
push (@CtyNameArray, $ctyname);
push (@PopEstimateArary, $popestimate2008);
push (@BirthsArray, $births2008);
push (@DeathsArray, $deaths2008);
}
$size = @BirthsArray;

while ($i < $size)
{
if($SumLevArray[$i] == " 040"){
$temp = $BirthsArray[$i]/$PopEstimateArary[$i]/541;
if(($lowestBirthRates > $temp) &&($temp > 0)){
$lowestBirthRates = $temp;
}
if($highestBirthRates < $temp){
$highestBirthRates = $temp;
}

}
$i = $i + 1;
}

print "\n";

print "Lowest birth rate in LOW-STATE: ";
print $lowestBirthRates;
print " per 541\n";

print "Highest birth rate in HIGH-STATE: ";
print $highestBirthRates;
print " per 541\n";

print "In Washington:\n";

print " Lowest birth rate in LOW-COUNTY County, WA: x.xxx per 541\n";

print " Highest birth rate in HIGH-COUNTY County, WA: x.xxx per 541\n";


close (FILE);
exit
```

Comment: **Always** start a Perl program with `use strict; use warnings;` and when you open a file, test to see if you succeeded as perl the [examples in the perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

Comment: And don't roll your own CSV parser, use [Text::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Text::CSV), it is faster and handles lots of edge cases.

Comment: @Quentin : In principle I agree with the `Text::CSV` recommendation but it looks like the OP has a long way to go before they are even comfortable with using modules. It's all part of the learning curve

Comment: I fixed my code and i get my answers to be   Lowest birth rate in LOW-STATE: 1.96871788504776e-05 per 541
Highest birth rate in HIGH-STATE: 3.84968878227209e-05 per 541. how do i get rid of the "e"?

Comment: @user977154 : That should be asked as another question. Do accept an answer if it helped you.

Comment: @user977154 look into [`printf`](http://p3rl.org/printf) and [`sprintf`](http://p3rl.org/sprintf) for printing and storing with formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond using Text::CSV as others have suggested, just for fun I have rewritten the code as I might have written it. It includes many of the suggestions made here and a few of my personal style choices. If you have any questions about it please ask. Also if you can post some sample data, I can check to see that it works.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $lowestBirthRates = 100000000;
my $highestBirthRates = 0;

my $filename = 'census2008.txt';
open (my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Cannot open $filename: $!";

my %data;

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ($sumlev, $stname,$ctyname,$popestimate2008,$births2008,$deaths2008) = split(",");

  push (@{$data{SumLev}}, $sumlev);
  push (@{$data{StName}}, $stname);
  push (@{$data{CtyName}}, $ctyname);
  push (@{$data{PopEstimate}}, $popestimate2008);
  push (@{$data{Births}}, $births2008);
  push (@{$data{Deaths}}, $deaths2008);
}

my $i = 0;
my $size = @{$data{Births}};

while ($i < $size) {

  if ( $data{SumLev}[$i] eq " 040" ){
  #if ( $data{SumLev}[$i] == 40 ){

    my $temp = $data{Births}[$i] / $data{PopEstimate}[$i] / 541;

    if( $lowestBirthRates > $temp && $temp > 0 ){
      $lowestBirthRates = $temp;
    }

    if ( $highestBirthRates < $temp ){
      $highestBirthRates = $temp;
    }

  }

  $i++;
}

print <<REPORT;
Lowest birth rate in LOW-STATE: $lowestBirthRates per 541
Highest birth rate in HIGH-STATE: $highestBirthRates per 541
In Washington:
Lowest birth rate in LOW-COUNTY County, WA: x.xxx per 541
Highest birth rate in HIGH-COUNTY County, WA: x.xxx per 541
REPORT
```

if you have the luxury of having Perl version 5.14 or greater installed, you can use an even clearer syntax, where `push` can take references directly, and where `each` can give the index in question as well as the value.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use 5.14.0;

my $lowestBirthRates = 100000000;
my $highestBirthRates = 0;

my $filename = 'census2008.txt';
open (my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Cannot open $filename: $!";

my %data = (
  SumLev => [],
  StName => [],
  CtyName => [],
  PopEstimate => [],
  Births => [],
  Deaths => [],
);

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  my ($sumlev, $stname,$ctyname,$popestimate2008,$births2008,$deaths2008) = split(",");

  push ($data{SumLev}, $sumlev);
  push ($data{StName}, $stname);
  push ($data{CtyName}, $ctyname);
  push ($data{PopEstimate}, $popestimate2008);
  push ($data{Births}, $births2008);
  push ($data{Deaths}, $deaths2008);
}

while (my ($i, $births) = each $data{Births}) {

  if ( $data{SumLev}[$i] eq " 040" ){
  #if ( $data{SumLev}[$i] == 40 ){

    my $temp = $births / $data{PopEstimate}[$i] / 541;

    if( $lowestBirthRates > $temp && $temp > 0 ){
      $lowestBirthRates = $temp;
    }

    if ( $highestBirthRates < $temp ){
      $highestBirthRates = $temp;
    }

  }
}

print <<REPORT;
Lowest birth rate in LOW-STATE: $lowestBirthRates per 541
Highest birth rate in HIGH-STATE: $highestBirthRates per 541
In Washington:
Lowest birth rate in LOW-COUNTY County, WA: x.xxx per 541
Highest birth rate in HIGH-COUNTY County, WA: x.xxx per 541
REPORT
```

Finally here is an implementation using [`Tie::Array::CSV`](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aCSV) which I wrote to be able to use a CSV file just like a 2D array in Perl (i.e. Array of ArrayRefs). It uses `Text::CSV` to do the parsing and `Tie::File` to do line access. This means that you don't need to store all the data in memory like in the previous examples.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::Array::CSV;

my $lowestBirthRates = 100000000;
my $highestBirthRates = 0;

my $filename = 'census2008.txt';
tie my @data, 'Tie::Array::CSV', $filename
  or die "Cannot tie $filename: $!";


foreach my $row (@data) {
  my ($sumlev, $stname, $ctyname, $popest, $births, $deaths) = @$row;

  if ( $sumlev eq " 040" ){
  #if ( $sumlev == 40 ){

    my $temp = $births / $popest / 541;

    if( $lowestBirthRates > $temp && $temp > 0 ){
      $lowestBirthRates = $temp;
    }

    if ( $highestBirthRates < $temp ){
      $highestBirthRates = $temp;
    }

  }
}

print <<REPORT;
Lowest birth rate in LOW-STATE: $lowestBirthRates per 541
Highest birth rate in HIGH-STATE: $highestBirthRates per 541
In Washington:
Lowest birth rate in LOW-COUNTY County, WA: x.xxx per 541
Highest birth rate in HIGH-COUNTY County, WA: x.xxx per 541
REPORT
```

Answer (score 4):

The best tool to help you out here is [`use strict; use warnings;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings). Make it a point to put it at the top of every script you write as it will save you a ton of time debugging trivial issues.

Here, there are a couple of `i`s that are missing their `$` sigil.

Also, consider studying the Perl data structure cookbook: [`perldoc perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html). An array of hashes (technically hashrefs) would be a more scalable choice of data structure to store your data.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
open (FILE, 'census2008.txt') or die $!;
```

The open may be failing without you knowing it.

Comment: ya it didn't work, i am mainly having trouble with lowest birth rate.

Comment: then i think @Dan has your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

When you print something, ending it with a newline will cause it to be printed immediately, otherwise the text goes to the print buffer but the buffer is not flushed.

Comment: its printing out zero now, do you know why it would do that?

Comment: even when i take out the lowestbirthrate = 0 it still equals zero :(

Answer (score 1):

You should unbuffer stdout.

Add the following after `#!/usr/bin/perl`

```
$| = 1;
```

Having said that, here are a couple other things I would suggest:

1.) At minimum `use strict;`    (`use warnings` is also advised)

Strict will force you to use "my" to declare your variables where you don't already do so.  I can't tell you the number of times I've seen a programmer search and search for a bug that is easily detectable when turning on strict checking.  (Typos on var names is a common one)

2.) Use the following for open

```
open($FILE, "<", 'census2008.txt') || die("Cannot open file!");
```

This will not only inform you if a file can't be opened for writing (due to the use of `die`),
but using `$FILE` instead of a raw file handle will cause the file to be closed automatically when it
goes out of scope.

Comment: That should be `open $FILE, '<', ...` (note the less than, not greater than sign

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason when I was typing it up I forgot the file was the data he was processing and not a file he was writing the result too.

Comment: It is not possible to "unbuffer stdout" as perl uses stdio.h, which is a buffered library. Setting $|=1 enables autoflush, it does not unbuffer stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your first lines of code to:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$| = 1; #

open (FILE, 'census2008.txt');
```

After solving the errors/warnings that are appearing, all should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

To access the array you use i instead of $i as index. 
Beyond this, I don't understand what you want to do inside the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in the line:

```
if($SumLevArray[$i] == " 040"){
```

This line is evaluated to true for many values of `$SumLevArray[$i]` ie `"40", "040", "  00040  "`

if `$SumLevArray[$i]` is an integer, this line should be:

```
if($SumLevArray[$i] == 40){
```

if `$SumLevArray[$i]` is a string, this line should be:

```
if($SumLevArray[$i] eq " 040"){
```