# Perl subroutine return an empty value

Tags: perl

I'm fairly new to perl so sorry if this is a newbie question.

As far as I understand perl, I can do this:

```
sub BuildAndroidRessourceArgument()
{
    my @xmlResFiles = @_;
    my $fileCnt = @_;
    my $index = 0;
    my $aaptResArg = "-F ";

    foreach( @xmlResFiles )
    {
        $index = $index + 1;
        if( $index == $fileCnt )
        {
            $aaptResArg = $aaptResArg.$_;
        }
        else
        {
            $aaptResArg = $aaptResArg.$_." -F ";
        }

    }
    print "$aaptResArg\n";
    return( $apptResArg );
}
```

When I print my aaptResArg in here I have the correct value but then:

```
my ( $aaptResArg ) = BuildAndroidRessourceArgument( @xmlResFiles );
print "$aaptResArg\n";
```

When I print after returning the value it prints nothing.

So as far as I know this code should work, if it prints in the function their's no reason why it shouldn't print when returning the value right ?

Comment: [Why use strict and warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)

Comment: You should put "use strict;" at the top of ALL of your Perl programs!

Comment: `use strict; use strict; use strict; use strict; use strict;` for the love of the Flying Spaghetti Monster, `use strict;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mis-spelled. Make it:

```
return($aaptResArg);
```

Answer (score 12):

You have misspelt the variable `$aaptResArg` as `$apptResArg`. This will have been caught had you made use of the [`strict`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) pragma.

Remember to always:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Quoting [Larry Wall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall):

> I *know* it's weird, but strict vars already comes very, very close to
>   partitioning the crowd into those who can deal with local lexicals and
>   those who can't.
>                -- Larry Wall in <199710050130.SAA04762@wall.org>