# Show output from Perl script in Matlab in real time

Tags: perl, matlab

I have matlab function that calls a Perl script which converts a large text file to binary for use in Matlab. See here for Perl script details: [Parsing unsorted data from large fixed width text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567774/parsing-unsorted-data-from-large-fixed-width-text)

My Matlab function looks something like this

```
function convertMyData(dataFileName)

%Do some checks on the data
disp('Done Checking Stuff!');

%Process data file with Perl
perl('myPerlScript.pl',dataFileName)

% More Processing on the Binary output from Perl
disp('All Done!');
```

In the perl script are some print statements showing the progress of the script since it can take several minutes to convert. Something like this:

```
while ($line = <INFILE>) {
    if ($lineCount % 100000 == 0){ #Display Progress every 100,000 lines
        print "On Line: ".$lineCount."\n";
    }
    #PROCESS LINE DATA HERE 
    $lineCount ++; 
} # END WHILE <INFILE>
print "Finished Reading: ".$lineCount." Lines\n";
```

The problem is that in Matlab all of my "On Line: XXXXX" `print` statements just get dumped to Matlab's default `ans` variable once the script completes instead of actually displayed at the prompt like Matlab's `disp()` function.

So how (if possible) do you get an external program's output to show up at the Matlab prompt while it is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do it. MATLAB passes the control to perl interpreter and then just get back the results.

There is one workaround that worked for me. First add **`local $|=1;`** inside your perl script to turn on STDOUT autoflush. Before any output to STDOUT. (See, for example, [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch07_13.htm) for more details on flushing buffer.) Then call perl using `system` function:

```
system(['"path_to_perl\perl.exe" test.pl ' dataFileName]);
```

Double-quotes are important if your perl interpreter is located in a path with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the built-in `perl` command. It will run perl interpreter and return result. I think that you need to put your output in a variable named `result`.

From the documentation:

> result = perl(...) returns the results of attempted Perl call to result.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, and goole lead me to your question.

Finally, on windows, I use the following matlab code, so solve my problem.

```
cmdString = 'start /WAIT ';
cmdString = [cmdString 'C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl extract_tti_trace.pl "' fullname '"'];
dos(cmdString)
```