# Counting to Scalar Value

Tags: perl, for-loop, foreach, counting, scalar

So I have a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (1..10) {
    print "#", $t, "\n";
 }
```

But I also have a scalar:

```
$number = 5;
```

Can I count from 1 to the scalar like so?

```
 foreach (1..$number) {
    print "#", $t, "\n";
 }
```

When I do this, the program simply outputs nothing. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: You are using the variable `$t` in the loop body, but do not define it. [`use strict; use warnings;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings) would have alerted you to your mistake. - `foreach my $t (1..$number) {` works as intended.

Comment: @daxim In the full code, I did define $v... sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Script:***

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $number = 5;

foreach (1..$number) {
  print "#$_\n";
}
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $number = 5;

print "#$_\n" for 1..$number;
```

***Output:***

```
#1
#2
#3
#4
#5
```