# Extracting data from XML using Perl via Xpath

Tags: perl, xpath

**The Situation:**
i am currently using XML::LibXML to extract data from an XML. I combine this with the Xpath of the XML elements and I can read and replace most values in the XML. However, I cant seem to access a particular data in the first tag of the XML. It is a rather important field but I have tried a few ways and still cant can manipulate that field.

**XML File:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
 <test **date_time="201111031006"** xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd">
    <msg_ver>0001</msg_ver>
    <sender_id>john</sender_id>
    <recipient_id>mike</recipient_id>
 </test>
```

I am trying to access the date_time field(in bold) but I cant seem to do so. I copied the XPath and tried as well and it wont work. I can actually change the  field and so forth but I can't change the date_time field. I am unable to even extract the data from the field let alone change it. Using the same function i can read, extract and save changes to fields ,  and .

**My Code**

```
 sub CHANGE_DATE()
  {
    my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
    my $doc    = $parser->parse_file($newfile);
    my $query  = "/tradenet/@date_time"; ## this is the actual XPATH
    my($node)   = $doc->findnodes($query);
        $node->setData("$date");

    $doc->toFile($newfile);
```

Thank you in advance for time taken to look thru this..

Answer (score 6):

Add [`use warnings;` and `use strict;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings) to the top of your script and it will tell you about a problem with your query. (Clue - `@date_time` looks like a variable name.)

Next you'll notice that `tradenet` is not the top-level tag in your test file.

Then, having fixed these you would find that `setData()` is not correct for an attribute, it's `setValue()`.

Then it will work.

All of this you would have discovered yourself if you'd converted the script into a small test and run it yourself before posting a question.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. My apologies for the typo as i had to edit the original XML document as it is classified. Hence the error of the XPATH name. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following xPath query /test/@date_time this should work.

```
my $query  = '/test/@date_time';
```

Also, W3School has excellent tutorial for xPath and libXML follows the same.

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/

Hope this will help.

Comment: You'll get a warning because you're trying to interpolate @date_time as a variable. See my answer above.