# splice: is it ok when the end of LENGTH is past of the array?

Tags: perl, splice

[splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html)

Is it OK, when `OFFSET` is within the array but the end of `LENGTH` is past the end of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy to try.

```
$ perl -wE'
   my @a = "a".."e";
   my @b = splice @a, 2, 10;
   say 0+@b, " elements were removed.";
   say 0+@a, " elements remain."
'
3 elements were removed.
2 elements remain.
```

I have every confidence that this will not change.

Answer (score 1):

It seems valid. The doc say anything about this scenario. The below code illustrates that length past the boundary is valid.

```
@array = ('this','is','for','testing','this','is','for','testing');
@array1 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);


splice @array,5,100,@array1;

print join "\n", @array ;
```

Comment: Make a habit of using `use strict` and using code that is strict-compliant, i.e. `my @array = ...`. Also, it would serve you well to remember certain perl idioms, such as `my @array = qw(this is for testing this is for testing)` and `my @array1 = 1..10`. If your perl version is >= 5.10, you can use `use v5.10; say for @array`.

Comment: this is just a sample script, as such didn't warrant for **strict** et all. I missed **qw()** as was programming in many other languages. I agree those are valid points.

Comment: Since the only cost of using `strict` is a few more characters to type, and the gain is insurance against a great many trivial errors, I would say that there is never really any good reason to not `use strict`. Except possibly in one-liners. And if that does not appeal to you, consider the fact that using strict is such a good idea that your up- and downvotes sometimes rely on it.

Comment: If one knows what **use strict** for or for that matter **perl -w** then one knows when to use it and when not to. The fact that the functionalities of **use strict** aren't enforced in perl by default validates it.

Comment: It seems valid. But could someone say - if the code breaks in some future release - why did you use `splice` in way not documented?

Comment: @tuxuday Except that 99% of the reasons to not use strict and warnings is laziness. And a misguided laziness, at that, because not using these two pragmas will actually cause you more work in the long run.

Comment: @sid_com In what way is it not documented?

Comment: @tuxuday See this question for more info http://stackoverflow.com/q/8023959/725418

Comment: @TMP In the sense, that I didn't see something where it is described what happens, when the end of `LENGTH` is past the end of the array.