# Accessing global hash in a subroutine in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, global-variables, subroutine

I have created a global hash and when I try to access that hash from within a Perl sub routine, it is not able to access it.

I have declared it as:

```
`%HASH = ();`
```

and trying to access it in a subroutine as :

```
$HASH{$key} = $value;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is the hash declared before the sub in the same file?  Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings` on?  Post some more code

Comment: Show some relevant code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I was pushing the hash value in an array using:
push (@{$HASH{$key}}, $value) and did not sort my array so couldnot find the value and it seemed to me that it could not access it. My bad, thanks for the help :)

Comment: @iDev You are not `push`ing *"in an array"* but in a (anonymous) array reference **INSIDE** your hash. Note that it will be created if it doesn't exist. See the output of [Data::Dumper](http://p3rl.org/Data::Dumper) on your hash to learn more. Learn more about references in the [perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/perlreftut). In almost all situations, `use`ing [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict) and [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings) helps to find wrong stuff. [Learn more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)

Comment: Thanks memowe.. That was informative! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Works fine here:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

our %truth = (); # "global" truth: lexical name
                 # for the package variable %main::truth

sub add_to_truth {
    my ($thing, $value) = @_;
    $truth{$thing} = $value;
}

add_to_truth(answer => 42);
say $truth{answer};
```

**Output**:

```
42
```

Note that under [strict](http://p3rl.org/strict)ures you have to fully-qualify your "global" variables with their package name (`%main::truth` in this case) or create a lexically scoped local name for them with [**our**](http://p3rl.org/our). And programming today without strictures (and warnings) is *not a good thing*™. In fact, activating them would have told you something useful.

Comment: Is 'our' strictly necessary in this situation?  I tried it with 'my' and it worked as well.  As I understand it, 'our' is used when you want to share this with the whole package.