# What does v1, v2, etc stand for in Perl?

Tags: perl, special-characters

I have an array of arrays that I am trying to print out (used to grab SQL database info):

```
my $variables_array = [[u1, answer1, Uvalue], ["v1", u2, v2, answer2, Vvalue]];
```

When I print out `$variables_array` all of the variables except for `v2` are printed out with the formatting I have above.  I searched *google/SO* and could not find any special significance for `v#` in Perl. I noticed that *notepad++* changes the color of `v#` in the array of arrays indicating it is some kind of special variable, but I cannot tell what it is?  Can someone please shed some light on this for me, I'm confused.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings

Comment: As FMc cryptically points out, adding `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to the top of your script will help point you in the right direction. Including those in every Perl script you ever write is good programming practice.

Comment: thanks, yep I had use strict and use warnings at the top of my calling   file and also the module that I am calling.  I did have no strict qw(subs) at the top of my calling file, I figured that the use strict in the module would take care of any major problems.  I was just confused why u2 was okay as a bareword, but not v2, or v3, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perl has a lot of different literals

- Numbers like `123`, `123.0`, `1.23e2`, `0x7b`
- String literals `"abc"`, `'abc'`, `q/abc/`, …
- Barewords

  - Barewords look like function calls without a param list
  - In special places, this is OK even under strict: `Foo::Bar->new()`
  - without `strict 'refs'`, barewords that don't signify subs are treated as strings.
  - the LHS of the fat comma `=>` is always autoquoted
  - Barewords with leading minus are always strings, unless they are file-test operators. `-abc eq "-abc"`
- V-strings (V as in vector, or version). `v1.2.3`

V-strings consist of a sequence of numbers that are seperated by a period. Each of the numbers is translated to a corresponding character. As they are strings, they can be compared with `lt`, `gt`, etc.

They are good for e.g. IP addresses, or version numbers. They are not good for being printed out, as low numbers signify unprintable characters.

```
$ perl -E'say v49.50.51'
123
```

The moral of the story? Always `use strict; use warnings;`, and maybe look into the `qw//` quoting operator:

```
my $variables_array = [[qw/u1 answer1 Uvalue/], [qw/v1 u2 v2 answer2 Vvalue/]];
# or verbose:
my $variables_array = [['u1', 'answer1', 'Uvalue'], ['v1', 'u2', 'v2', 'answer2', 'Vvalue']];
```

(`qw` does not interpolate, splits the string at any whitespace, and is equal to the list of strings)

Comment: In ASCII, the `0x02` stands for `STX`, the “start of text” This is an unprintable character. `"\x02" eq v2` is true.

Comment: brillant, thank you, I like the qw of the inner anonymous array, I will use that.  Very through explanation.

Comment: See  also [Perl Scalar Value Constructors](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Scalar-value-constructors) and the sub-section on 'Version Strings'.

Answer (score 3):

With no strict or warnings, I get:

```
$variables_array: [
                    [
                      'u1',
                      'answer1',
                      'Uvalue'
                    ],
                    [
                      'v1',
                      'u2',
                      v2,
                      'answer2',
                      'Vvalue'
                    ]
                  ]
```

amon's answer explains that they are ["barewords"](http://perl5maven.com/barewords-in-perl). Barewords are deprecated in almost all contexts (perhaps not command-line scripts, though).

Notice that it quotes `'v1'` but not `'v2'`, that because a version string--a number beginning with a `v`--are legal literals in Perl.