# html tags not working in perl

Tags: html, linux, perl

I am new to perl scripting and i am trying to execute following code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$html = "Content-Type: text/html

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Hello World</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H4>Hello World</H4>
<P>
Your IP Address is $ENV{REMOTE_ADDR}
<P>
<H5>Have a nice day</H5>
</BODY>
</HTML>";

print $html;
```

when i execute the file its just printing whole $html content within quotation marks and not executing the html tags.
Can anybody tell what am i doing wrong . I have my test.pl file in root directory and have tried " chmod 775 test.pl" command.

Thank you

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What is the output of `curl -i http://example.com/test.pl`?

Comment: @Zoidberg — Presumably he means "The browser is treating the output as text instead of HTML so the tags are being displayed instead of treated as headings et al".

Comment: By the way, that should be `#!/usr/bin/perl` (note the extra `/`), though that won't solve your problem.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should not write Perl programs without [`use strict; use warnings`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings).

Comment: I assume you need to configure your web server (Apache?) to *execute* this, rather than just display it. More info on your environment would be useful

Comment: You *do* know that the header will have an effect only if it is served as an HTTP message? Running the program from a command line will just display the text as it is; you need to get your program executed by an HTTP server as CGI code.

Comment: @IshanKaushik — That was an example URL. Use the URL to your script.

Comment: @Borodin, make that an answer

Comment: @Quentin, He's running the script from bash.

Comment: @ikegami — I don't think he has said that. He might be, but as far as I can tell, that is speculation at present.

Comment: @Quentin, It's the only way he could get that output.

Comment: @Kaushik Nothing to do with Linux, that's to do with not understanding the difference between a web app and an app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are running your program from a command line. In those circumstances the HTTP data type will have no effect, and the whole string will be printed to the console.

To get the string served as an HTTP message you need to put the program on an HTTP server, which can be either a remote system or your own computer with server software installed and configured.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the shebang line is not correct, it is missing the first /.

You could always able to execute perl code in this way:

```
path_to_your_perl your_program
```

Like:

```
/usr/bin/perl test.pl
```