# How to declare perl variable without using "my"

Tags: perl, variables

I'm new to Perl programming.  I've noticed that every time I want to declare a new variable, I should use the `my` keyword before that variable if `strict` and `warnings` are on (which I was told to do, for reasons also I do not know.)

So how to declare a variable in perl without using `my` and without getting warnings?

**My question is:** Is it possible to declare a variable without using `my` and without omitting the `use strict;` and `use warnings;` and without getting warnings at all?

Comment: you can get rid of `use strict` and `-w` flag to stop using `my`...BUT THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED...using `my` will save you a lot of debugging time in future :)

Comment: Your question is very confusing. I *think* the problem is that you don't know what it means to "declare" a variable, and are misusing the term. You might want to read through [the Wikipedia article on "Declaration (computer programming)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declaration_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: Why don't you want to use `my`?

Comment: i diddnt say i dont want to, i'm just asking if it's possible

Comment: Yes: `use vars qw( $varname );`, or `our $varname;`, or subvert strict checking by using fully qualified names such as `$main::varname`.  But these are not synonyms for `my $varname;`.  They declare package globals rather than pad lexicals, and have varying scoping rules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two means of declaring lexical variables: `my` and `our`, but they're not interchangeable, as the lexical created by `our` is aliased to a package variable.

The `vars` pragma and `our` can be seen as means of declaring package variables.

`use strict;` wont die for declared variables, and `use warnings;` wont warn for declared variables (unless you count "used only once"), so I have no idea why you mentioned them.

Comment: i have encountered that term many times - 'packaged variable' what is it?

Comment: Perl has two types of variables, lexical and package (no "d") variables. Lexical variables are lexically-scoped, meaning the can only be seen in the block or file in which they are defined. Package variables are globally-scoped, meaning they can be accessed from anywhere in the program.

Comment: hey man @ikegami, i have a short question for you since you know everything, what does the '\' backslash do in this example: `*{caller(  )."::useful"} = \&useful;`

Comment: `\&useful` returns a code reference to sub `useful`. As a whole, that line exports `useful` to current sub's caller's package.

Comment: ...similar to \@array, \$scalar, etc, but for subs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an answer to both of your questions, emphasis added:

http://www.caveofprogramming.com/perl/perl-variables-%E2%80%94-declaring-and-using-variables-in-perl/

> The most important thing to say about variables in Perl, before we get
>   into any further details, is that you should always write use strict
>   and use warnings at the top of your program, then declare all
>   variables with `my`.
>
> use `strict` ensures that all variables must be declared with `my` (or
>   `local`) before you use them, helping to eliminate typos.
>
> use `warnings` ensures that your script will warn you about
>   uninitialized variables. **Always using strict and warnings will save
>   you a huge amount of time in the long run**.

See also:

[Why use strict and warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)

Comment: how does using `my` eliminate typos?

Comment: without `my` perl will declare a variable whenever you use a new variable name. say you have `$name = "hello"`, and you use `$name` in your code. By mistake you use `$nme` and forget the `a`. perl will think you are using a variable `$nme` which is initialized to `null` by default. if you use `my`, perl you give error that variable `nme` is not defined. Thus, eliminate typos and save debugging time.

Comment: That second paragraph of that quote wrong. `local` does not declare variables -- it only works on existing variables -- and won't affect `strict` whatsoever.

Comment: Today I got this that `local` does not declare variables. Thanks @ikegami

Answer (score 2):

It's good practice to use `my` since that defines the variable in local scope. Otherwise you'll end up with a mess of global variables which are often the source of bugs.

But if you really don't want to use `my`, then simply omit the lines `use strict` and `use warnings`.

> [strict vars (perldoc)](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html)
>
> This generates a compile-time error if you access a variable that was neither explicitly declared (using any of my, our, state, or use vars ) nor fully qualified. (Because this is to avoid variable suicide problems and subtle dynamic scoping issues, a merely local variable isn't good enough.) See my, our, state, local, and vars.