# Backticks in directory query generate problems with pipe

Tags: perl, grep, pipe, ls

I'm trying to fill a Perl array with a list of file names in a directory,$dir, and I want to exclude directories.  My code is:

```
my @lsArray = `ls -p $dir | grep -v '/$'`;
```

But it creates this error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

I cant seem to find a combination of quotes which does this correctly.  Thanks....

Comment: [Why use strict and warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8023959/725418)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using backticks for something that perl can do perfectly fine on its own?

```
my @files = grep !-d, <$dir/*>;
```

Btw, your error is that `$'` is a perl predefined variable (postmatch) that gets interpolated, so the closing `'` is missing.

If you had used

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Perl would have told you what the problem was:

```
Use of uninitialized value $' in quoted execution (``, qx) at ...
```

Always use those two pragmas: Errors do not get less difficult to handle because you don't know about them.