# Getting error "Can't open input file No such file or directory" and I can't figure out why

Tags: perl

I have a script that will read a log.  The first three characters of the log are a code for that customer (i.e. xxx).  The program starts and runs then stops with this error.  The out.txt is located in the log directory for all customers up to a certain one.  This one has the same permissions as all the others.  The program stops, and nothing past that customer gets the file.

```
    $adminDir = "/data1/Scripts";
    $scriptDir =  "/data1/Scripts";
    chomp($toDay = `date +%m-%d-%y`);
    @prodDirs = ();
    open(DIRS, "$scriptDir/production_dirs") or warn "Can't open $scriptDir/production_dirs file: $!\n";
    $count = 0;
    while (<DIRS>) {
             if(index($_, '#') < 0) {
                    chomp($prodDirs[$count++] = $_);
             }
    }
    close(DIRS);

    foreach $jobDir (@prodDirs) {
            @dirFields = split(/\|/, $jobDir);
            $srcDir = $dirFields[0];
            $workDir = "$srcDir";
            $logFile = $workDir . "/log/" . $dirFields[11] . "log";
            $oldLog = $logFile;
            $oldLogBack = $oldLog . "." . $toDay;
            $newLog = $workDir . "/log/" . "out.txt";

            open(FILE, "<$logFile")|| die "Can't open input file $!";
            open(OUT, ">$newLog") || die "Can't open output file $!";
            while(<FILE>) {
                    print OUT if($_=~/(.*)(Jan  1)(.*?)/gs);
            }
     }
```

Comment: `use strict; use warnings;`

Comment: Use : `open(my $FILE, '<', $logFile)|| die "Can't open input file '$logfile' : $!";`

Comment: Why do you only `warn` if you cannot open the directory instead of `die`ing. Do you really want the rest of your program to run if you can't open the directory?

Comment: I used the "Can't open input file $logFile" and found out what was really wrong.  I'm sorry to have bothered the group with this question.  Thanks for the suggestions and help!

Comment: Voting to close.  OP already solved his problem.

Comment: If you understand your errors and reviewed given answers, please accept and close this question.

Answer (score 4):

A few quick notes.

**Why** use `strict` and `warnings`?

Using this will help you catch typographical errors more quickly and then move on to being able to find more significant problems.

Read:

- [perldoc strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html)
- [perldoc warnings](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html)
- [Why use strict and warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)

**Why** *three-arg* and not *two-arg* form of `open()` ?

Keep in mind that the `two-arg` form of open is broken. For example let's take a file called `' foo'`. Now this file has a leading whitespace at the beginning. So however you go to open it..

```
open FILE, ' foo'   || die $!;
open FILE, '< foo'  || die $!;
open FILE, '<  foo' || die $!;
```

See anything wrong here? None of these will work. Note also that If you accidentally use a filename with special characters, your code likely will not behave as you would as expect.

This approach is much cleaner and safe to use. Refer to [perldoc open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

```
open my $fh, '<', 'foo' or die "failed $!";
```

Things to remember

- Use the `three-arg` form of open
- Use `lexical scalars` to store filehandle references
- Avoid problems by using `or` instead of `||` to check the success of open

Answer (score 2):

I took your program and added in `use strict;` and `use warnings;`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $adminDir = "/data1/Scripts";
my $scriptDir =  "/data1/Scripts";

chomp( my $toDay = `date +%m-%d-%y` );
my @prodDir;
open(DIRS, "$scriptDir/production_dirs") or die "Can't open $scriptDir/production_dirs file: $!\n";

my $count = 0;
while ( <DIRS> ) {
    if ( index($_, '#') < 0 ) {
        chomp ( $prodDirs[$count++] = $_ );
    }
}
close(DIRS);

for my $jobDir (@prodDirs) {
    my @dirFields = split(/\|/, $jobDir);
    my $srcDir = $dirFields[0];
    my $workDir = "$srcDir";
    my $logFile = $workDir . "/log/" . $dirFields[11] . "log";
    my $oldLog = $logFile;
    my $oldLogBack = $oldLog . "." . $toDay;
    my $newLog = $workDir . "/log/" . "out.txt";

    open(FILE, "<" , $logFile)|| die "Can't open input file $!";
    open(OUT, ">", $newLog) || die "Can't open output file $!";
    while(<FILE>) {
        print OUT if($_=~/(.*)(Jan  1)(.*?)/gs);
    }
}
```

The error I get:

```
Global symbol "@prodDirs" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 16.
Global symbol "@prodDirs" requires explicit package name at ./test.pl line 21.
```

In line # 10, you initialized `@prodDir`, but then in your loop, you used `@prodDirs` (with an `s` on the end.

This is why everyone is saying to you "*Use `use strict;` and `use warnings;`*". These two pragmas catch 90% of your programming errors.