# Skipping SQLite operation if primary key already in table

Tags: database, perl, sqlite

I've populated an array with hashes of data from a JSON API that I want to load into a SQLite table. The (composite) primary key of this table is generated such that a later JSON pull won't contain any new information associated with an old primary key, but /will/ contain new information with new primary keys. (Specifically, it's keyed by the combination of date and an ID uniquely identifying each object I need information on.)

Rather than having to fiddle awkwardly with the API parameters, I'd rather just have the program discard information already in the table given the above, but I can't get the loop to skip properly.

```
use DBI;
use 5.010;

#DLing information, processing, sanitising, etc. omitted

foreach my $hash (@{$data{$key}}) {
    my %data = %{$hash->{'row'}};
    my $date = $data{'date'};
    my $id = $data{'id'};
    my @pkey = [$date, $id]; #Generate a Perl array corresponding to the primary key, e.g. ['2013-09-10','0001']
    next if @pkey ~~ @allkeys; #Trying to use the 5.010 smart match operator to check if primary key already processed, and skip the entry if it is
    push(@allkeys,[@pkey]); 
    #Other stuff omitted--nothing to do with the pkey issue#
    my $sql = sprintf "INSERT INTO %s (date,id,low,high,avg) VALUES ('%s', %s, %s, %s, %s)",
        $table, $date, $id, $low, $high, $avg; #Values initialised earlier in script
    $dbh->do($sql);
}
```

That's what I'm trying at the moment, but it still dies on the first operation; simpler would be to have the loop skip for the particular error type 'DBD::SQLite::db do failed: columns date, typeID are not unique' rather than dying, but I haven't the foggiest where to begin with that.

For completeness, the database schema:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
            date TEXT,
            id INTEGER,
            low REAL,
            high REAL,
            avg REAL,
            PRIMARY KEY (date,id)
    );
```

Comment: Always [`use strict; use warnings;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8023959/133939)

Comment: This is not your *actual* database schema; please fix the errors.

Comment: Schema is incorrect: shouldn't `typeID` be `id`?

Comment: Gah, sorry; I'll get on that. I renamed the variables to make this easier to see out of context, but obviously missed that. Same with use strict and warnings; omitted them because I thought it was a given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To not insert records that would violate a `UNIQUE` constraint, use [INSERT OR IGNORE](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html):

```sql
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO TheRealTableName(date,id,low,high,avg) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: Works perfectly: cheers! New to SQL and not much more experienced with Perl, hence the perhaps daft question.