# Can not retrieve hash reference in perl

Tags: regex, perl, bash, hash

Hi I am trying to save a hash reference in file named 'chksum' and retrieve it later when needed. But it gives me an error.

## Test.pl

```
  #!/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl
use Storable;
use File::Find qw(find);
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_base64);
use Data::Dumper;
#=head
######################
#Collect checksum    #
######################
my $files = {};
$files_ref = retrieve('checksum');
find(sub {
        my $file = $File::Find::name;
        return if ! length($file);
        my ($size, $mtime) = (stat $_)[7, 9];
        open (FILE, $file);
        $chksum = md5_base64(<FILE>);
        $files->{$file} = {
            local_is_dir => (-d _ ? 1 : 0),
            local_size   => $size,
            local_mtime  => $mtime,
            chksum       => $chksum,
        };
        #$ref = $files->{$file} || = {};
        my $ref = $files_ref->{$file} ||= {};
        if ($chksum != $ref->{chksum}) {print $file;}
    }, '/root/ftp_kasi/');

#print Dumper(\$files);
store \$files, 'checksum';
```

## Output

```
root@- [~/ftp_kasi]# perl test.pl 
Not a HASH reference at test.pl line 25.
```

Can somebody help me out on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `print Dumper $files_ref, $file;` before assignment to inspect. Also consider using strict and warnings => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings

Comment: Thanks I used strict and warnings but no other error messages. "Not a HASH reference at test.pl line 25" appears on the assignment line. Therefore print Dumper $ref not yielding any results.

Comment: `print Dumper $files_ref, $file;` but before $ref assigment. `$files_ref` is not hashref as it seems.

Comment: I am able to print $files_ref using Dumper. But when I print just any key $files_ref it gives me Not a HASH reference error. Can I not print it using print $files_ref->{'key'}

Comment: update your question with output of `print Dumper $files_ref, $file;`

Comment: I reduced code length so that problem can be highlighted.
    use Storable;
    use Data::Dumper;
    my $config = {
            host      => '168.144.97.101',
        };
    store \$config, 'stalk.txt';
    $ref = retrieve ("stalk.txt");
    print $config->{'host'};
    print "\n";
    print Dumper $ref;
    print $ref->{'host'};
    print "\n";

Output
======

    168.144.97.101
    $VAR1 = \{
                'host' => '168.144.97.101'
              };
    Not a HASH reference at stalk.pl line 11.

Comment: You can see that once I can not print just one key value even after successfully retrieving hash from file. (I am able to print $ref using Dump)@mpapec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're storing reference to hashref, when you actually want to use hashref only, so replace

```
store \$files, 'checksum';
```

with

```
store $files, 'checksum';
```

Comment: Cool. That was the issue. You solved my problem. Big thanks.. :)

Answer (score 0):

`$ref` is empty because the `||=` operator does not do what you think it does.
What about using `||` instead?

Comment: I did try using 'my $ref = $files_ref->{$file} || {};' . But it is also giving the same error.