# Get particular sub set of elements from an array returned by a function

Tags: perl

I don't have too much practice in perl but I remember from my old days that you could get some elements of an array returned by a function in a single line, saving you time and code as not to save stuff first to a temporary array just to use a couple of their elements.

For instance

```
($a,$b,$c)=split(/:/, "stack:over:flow"); 
print "$b $c" # prints "over flow"
```

Or even

```
($a)=(split(/:/, "stack:over:flow"))[2];
print $a # prints "flow"
```

Let's say that I am only interested on the second and third elements ("over" and "flow") from the output of `split`.
Can I do something like

```
($a,$b)=(split(/:/, "stack:over:flow"))[2,3];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost. Remember that arrays are zero-indexed.

```
my ( $first, $second ) = ( split /:/, "stack:over:flow" )[1,2];
```

Other points to note:

- [`use strict; use warnings;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8023959/133939)
- Avoid using `$a` and `$b` as variable names. They are special package variables intended to be used inside `sort` blocks.

Answer (score 2):

You can also assign to [`undef`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/undef.html) anything you aren't interested in:

```
my (undef, $over, $flow) = split /:/, 'stack:over:flow';
```

Answer (score 0):

well, yes, you can get it as there is an method to slice an array by index.
here list a script you can run

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/perl
  2 use strict;
  3 use warnings;
  4
  5 my $text = "first:second:third";
  6 my @array = split(':', $text);
  7 my @new_array = @array[1, 2];
  8 print "@new_array\n";
```