# Matching in Perl does not work

Tags: perl, match

I'm trying to match a line that starts with >, but does not work...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while ($lines = <>) {
  $count++;
  if (/^\#/) {
    next;
  }
  elsif (/^>/) {
    print "hola";
  }

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!

Comment: why? strict is annoying.

Comment: How can it be annoying? It's completely unnoticeable if you have no errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8024241/589924

Comment: Change it to `while (<>)` if you want to use the default var `$_` on those regex's. Or `while ($lines = <>) { $_ = $lines;, etc ... }`

Comment: @user2886545: It might be better to get used to the minimal annoyance that `use strict` causes you than the presumably more annoying problem of being unable to find the bugs that it would highlight.

Comment: @ikegami: It is far from unnoticeable. `use strict` may well cause a compilation failure on a fully correct program that works fine without it.

Comment: @Borodin, I said "a program with no errors", not "a program that runs fine"

Comment: `use strict` is an essential part of the toolbox of any good Perl programmer. Why should we spend time helping you find problems that `use strict` would show you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to match $_ and not $lines
change it to

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while ($lines = <>) {
  $count++;
  if ($lines =~ /^\#/) {
    next;
  }
  elsif ($lines =~ /^>/) {
    print "hola";
  }

}
```

Comment: He may also be [Suffering from Buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html), as there's no `\n` in his `print` statement.

Comment: (Perhaps renaming `$lines` to `$line` would be a nice addition too.)

Comment: `$lines` is a dreadful name for a variable that contains the last line read from a file.