# perl simple matching yet not matching it

Tags: perl

in blah.txt:

```
/a/b/c-test
```

in blah.pl

```
  1 my @dirs;
  2 $ws = '/a/b/c-test/blah/blah';       <--- trying to match this
  3 sub blah{
  4     my $err;
  5     open(my $fh, "<", "blah.txt") or $err = "catn do it\n";
  6     if ($err) {
  7         print $err;
  8         return;
  9     } else {
 10         while(<$fh>){
 11             chomp;
 12             push @dirs, $_;
 13         }
 14     }
 15     close $fh;
 16     print "successful\n";
 17 }
 18
 19
 20 blah();
 21
 22 foreach (@dirs) {
 23     print "$_\n"; #/a/b/c-test
 24     if ($_ =~ /$ws/ ) {                  <--- didnt match it
 25         print "GOT IT!\n";
 26     } else {
 27         print "didnt get it\n";
 28     }
 29 }
~
```

perl blah.pl

```
successful
/a/b/c-test
didnt get it
```

I am not quite sure why it is not matching.
Anyone know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider,

```
if ($ws =~ /$_/ ) {
```

instead of,

```
if ($_ =~ /$ws/ ) {
```

as `/a/b/c-test/blah/blah` contains `/a/b/c-test` string, not otherwise.

As a side notes:

- use at least [strict and warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)
- read and process file in `while()` loop instead of filling array first
- if you must fill array, use `my @dirs = <$fh>; chomp(@dirs);`

Comment: i was hoping to save it in the array first because this will be called multiple times and i dont want to keep opening the file