# How can I get this basic Perl sub program that sorts to work properly?

Tags: perl, sorting

I am brand new to Perl. Can someone help me out and give me a tip or a solution on how to get this sorting sub program to work. I know it has something to do with how arrays are passed to sub programs. I searched online and did not find an answer that I was satisfied with... I also like the suggestions the helpful S.O. users give me too. I would like to have the program print the sorted array in the main sub program. Currently, it is printing the elements of the array @a in original order. I want the sub program to modify the array so when I print the array it is in sorted order. Any suggestions are appreciated. Of course, I want to see the simplest way to fix this.

```
sub sort {

    my @array = @_;

    my $i;
    my $j;
    my $iMin;

    for ( $i = 0; $i < @_ - 1; $i++ ) {

        $iMin = $i;

        for ( $j = $i + 1; $j < @_; $j++ ) {

            if ( $array[$j] < $array[$iMin] ) {

                $iMin = $j;
            }
        }

        if ( $iMin != $i ) {

            my $temp = $array[$i];
            $array[$i] = $array[$iMin];
            $array[$iMin] = $temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Then call from a main sub program:

```
sub main {

    my @a = (-23,3,234,-45,0,32,12,54,-10000,1);

    &sort(@a);
    my $i;

    for ( $i = 0; $i < @a; $i++ ) {

        print "$a[$i]\n";

    }
}

main;
```

Comment: I assume you're writing your own `sort` function for an assignment, so the built-in `sort` is out?

Comment: I am writing a sort sub program, but not for an assignment. I just want to see how Perl works. I suppose I could do that but I want to see if there is an easy fix for this.

Comment: Using `sort` is much easier; see the code samples in my answer. Generally speaking, in perl, using your own sorting mechanisms are The Wrong Thing; the correct approach is to tell `sort` how you want things sorted and let it do the work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When your sub does the following assignment `my @array = @_`, it is creating a copy of the passed contents.  Therefore any modifications to the values of `@array` will not effect `@a` outside your subroutine.

Following the clarification that this is just a personal learning exercise, there are two solutions.

1) You can [`return`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html) the sorted array and assign it to your original variable

```
sub mysort {
    my @array = @_;
    ...
    return @array;
}

@a = mysort(@a)
```

2) Or you can pass a reference to the array, and work on the reference:

```
sub mysort {
    my $arrayref = shift;
    ...
}

mysort(\@a)
```

Also, it's probably a good idea to not use a sub named [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) since that's that's a builtin function.  Duplicating your code using perl's sort:

```
@a = sort {$a <=> $b} @a;
```

Also, the for loops inside your sub should be rewritten to utilize the last index of an `@array`, which is written as `$#array`, and the [`range operator ..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) which is useful for incrementors :

```
for ( my $j = $i + 1; $j <= $#array; $j++ ) {

# Or simpler:

for my $j ($i+1 .. $#array) {
```

And finally, because you're new, I should pass on that all your scripts should start with [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html).  For reasons why: [`Why use strict and warnings?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Among other things I have seen today in my dive into Perl, I noticed that I have quite a bit of shorthand notation to learn. I know the code I wrote wasn't elegant by any means. This answer was very helpful though. Thanks!

Comment: @ikegami Updated answer preface

Answer (score 2):

With very few, rare exceptions the simplest (and easiest) way to sort stuff in perl is simply to use the `sort` builtin.

`sort` takes an optional argument, either a block or a subname, which can be used to control how sort evaluates which of the two elements it is comparing at any given moment is greater.

See [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) on [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/) for further information.

If you require a "natural" sort function, where you get the sequence `0, 1, 2, 3, ...` instead of `0, 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 21, 22, 3, ...`, then use the perl module [Sort::Naturally](http://search.cpan.org/~bingos/Sort-Naturally-1.03/lib/Sort/Naturally.pm) which is available on CPAN (and commonly available as a package on most distros).

In your case, if you need a pure numeric sort, the following will be quite sufficient:

```
use Sort::Naturally; #Assuming Sort::Naturally is installed

sub main {

    my @a = (-23,3,234,-45,0,32,12,54,-10000,1);

    #Choose one of the following
    @a = sort @a; #Sort in "ASCII" ascending order
    @a = sort { $b cmp $a } @a; #Sort in reverse of the above
    @a = nsort @a; #Sort in "natural" order
    @a = sort { ncmp($b, $a) } @a; #Reverse of the above

    print "$_\n" foreach @a; #To see what you actually got

}
```

It is also worth mentioning the `use sort 'stable';` pragma which can be used to ensure that sorting occurs using a stable algorithm, meaning that elements which are equal will not be rearranged relative to one another.

As a bonus, you should be aware that `sort` can be used to sort data structures as well as simple scalars:

```
#Assume @a is an array of hashes
@a = sort { $a->{name} cmp $b->{name} } @; #Sort @a by name key

#Sort @a by name in ascending order and date in descending order
@a = sort { $a->{name} cmp $b->{name} || $b->{date} cmp $a->{date} } @a;

#Assume @a is an array of arrays

#Sort @a by the 2nd element of the arrays it contains
@a = sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] } @a;

#Assume @a is an array of VERY LONG strings

#Sort @a alphanumerically, but only care about
#the first 1,000 characters of each string
@a = sort { substr($a, 0, 1000) cmp substr($b, 0, 1000) } @a;


#Assume we want to "sort" an array without modifying it:
#Yes, the names here are confusing. See below.
my @idxs = sort { $a[$a] cmp $a[$b] } (0..$#a);

print "$a[$_]\n" foreach @idxs;
#@idxs contains the indexes to @a, in the order they would have
#to be read from @a in order to get a sorted version of @a
```

As a final note, please remember that `$a` and `$b` are special variables in perl, which are pre-populated in the context of a sorting sub or sort block; the upshot is that if you're working with `sort` you can always expect `$a` and `$b` to contain the next two elements being compared, and should use them accordingly, but do NOT do `my $a;`, e.g., or use variables with either name in non-sort-related stuff. This also means that naming things `%a` or `@a`, or `%b` or `@b`, can be confusing -- see the final section of my example above.

Comment: `Sort::Naturally` is unnecessary when the list elements are numeric: `sort { $a <=> $b } @array`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot And? This is a learning exercise. Knowing how to handle things other than numbers is a good thing.