# Regex seems valid but doesn't work in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have the folowing regex verified by regex coach

```
(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)
```

this matches the `dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss` format, but in Perl I don't receive anything

My array contains these two entries

```
foo 24.03.2014 19:18:57 foobar foo bar
bar 24.03.2014 15:19:00 asdfasrwe jlkj
```

Here is my Perl program

```
use Try::Tiny;

foreach(@array) 
{
    try {
        my ($day, $month, $year,$hours, $minutes, $seconds) = ($_ =~ m/(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/);
        my $time= "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
        my $date= "$day.$month.$year";
    } catch {
         warn "caught error: $_";
    };
    print "Time: $time, Date: $date\n";
}
```

The output is

```
Time: , Date: 
Time: , Date:
```

As with regex coach, my regex is approved, and no exception is shown. I don't see my error. Where is the problem?

[on regex101 - it seems legitimate](http://regex101.com/r/dS5uA5)

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`!!!

Comment: That `try` block is a bit useless.  It contains nothing that might `die`.

Comment: use strict; use warnings; > now i received a few more infos, thy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as already stated is to include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of each and every script that you make: [`Why use strict and warnings?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)

Also, you're currently pulling out the individual time and date information, but then throwing it away to build your full date and time.  You could skip a step there and just use 2 capture groups to pull the date and time from the start.

Additionally, you'll eventually want to be exposed to [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) for working with date/times:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

my @array = (
    'foo 24.03.2014 19:18:57 foobar foo bar',
    'bar 24.03.2014 15:19:00 asdfasrwe jlkj', 
);

for (@array) {
    if (my ($date, $time) = $_ =~ m/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+) (\d+:\d+:\d+)/) {
        print "Time: $time, Date: $date\n";
    }
}

for (@array) {
    if (/([\d.]{10} [\d:]{8})/) {
        my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($1, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S");
        print $t, "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Are 'my $time' and 'my $date' local to the try block?
Can you print the values from within the try block?

Comment: It seems like i've ended up in a bad scoping problem. you pointed me in the right direction! thank you

Answer (score 4):

Had you applied `use strict` to your program wou would have seen that the `$time` and `$date` variables that you are printing haven't been declared, and so are different from the ones being defined within the `try` block.

Please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program you write. It is a simple measure that will reveal many simple mistakes like this.

By the way there is nothing in your `try` block that could cause a fatal error, so it may as well be written without the use of the `Try::Tiny` module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Try::Tiny;

my @array = (
  'foo 24.03.2014 19:18:57 foobar foo bar',
  'bar 24.03.2014 15:19:00 asdfasrwe jlkj', 
);

for (@array) {
    my ($time, $date);
    try {
        my ($day, $month, $year, $hours, $minutes, $seconds) = /(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+) (\d+):(\d+):(\d+)/;
        $time = "$hours:$minutes:$seconds";
        $date = "$day.$month.$year";
    }
    catch {
         warn "caught error: $_";
    };
    print "Time: $time, Date: $date\n";
}
```

**output**

```
Time: 19:18:57, Date: 24.03.2014
Time: 15:19:00, Date: 24.03.2014
```