# perl, getting nested hash from hash

Tags: perl

I don't understand what is wrong with this script:

```
%Region = (1 => {name => "nameVal"}, 2 => {name => "nameVal2"});
while(my($k, %v) = each %Region) {  
    print $k, $v{'name'}, "\n"; 
}
```

It doesn't print the value from the nested hash.

I tried with different commas, no effect.

perl v5.12.4, mac os

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your nested hash is `hashref` - a reference to a hash - so you need to access it this way using `->` to dereference.

```
%Region = (1 => {name => "nameVal"}, 2 => {name => "nameVal2"});
while(my($k, $v) = each %Region) {  
    print $k, $v->{'name'}, "\n"; 
}
```

It is a `hashref` because you used `{ }` to initialize your nested hash.

Comment: In addition it's a hashref *because* it's not a top-level variable.

Answer (score 3):

Always include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of EVERY perl script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %Region = (1 => {name => "nameVal"}, 2 => {name => "nameVal2"});
while(my($k, %v) = each %Region) {  
    print $k, $v{'name'}, "\n"; 
}
```

In this case, the warning would have been the following:

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected at scratch.pl line 5.
```

This is pointing out the fact that you're assigning single value, a reference, to a hash `%v` which expects an even-sized list, or key value pairs.

So we fix that line so it's assigning a reference to a scalar:

```
while(my($k, $v) = each %Region) {
```

You will now get the following error:

```
Global symbol "%v" requires explicit package name at input7.pl line 6.
```

There is no definition for `%v`, only our scalar with a reference, `$v`.  To dereference that variable and access a value, we use the arrow operator `->`

```
    print $k, $v->{'name'}, "\n";
```

Output is now what you desire:

```
2nameVal2
1nameVal
```

The lesson here is ALWAYS include `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of every perl script.  For more reasons why, check out: [`Why use strict and warnings?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)