# Replacing Hash key with another name in perl

Tags: perl, hash, substitution

I am trying to change key with another name . Tried below code but getting some error:

```
my @array = qw(1 hello ue hello 3 hellome 4 hellothere);
my %hash = @array;

foreach (Keys %hash) { 
   s/ue/u/g;
}
```

Output Error: Illegal modulus zero at test.pl line 35.

Answer (score 7):

Perl is case-sensitive. You are looking for [`keys`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/keys.html) (lowercase):

```
my @array = qw(1 hello ue hello 3 hellome 4 hellothere);
my %hash = @array;

foreach (keys %hash) {  # <-- 
   s/ue/u/g;
}
```

You should really [`use strict; use warnings;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings) at the top of all of your Perl modules/scripts. It will give you much better error messaging.

More to the point of your question, you can't update hash keys like that. You have to create a new key in the hash with the desired name, and delete the old key. You can do this nicely in a single line since [`delete`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html) returns the value of the hash key that was deleted.

```
use strict;
use warnings; 

my @array = qw(1 hello ue hello 3 hellome 4 hellothere);
my %hash = @array;

foreach my $key (keys %hash) {  # <-- 
   if ($key eq 'ue') {
      $hash{u} = delete $hash{$key};
   }
}
```

To tighten up the code even more, it's not actually necessary to iterate through the keys to determine if a specific key exists.  The following single line could replace the for loop:

```
$hash{u} = delete $hash{ue} if exists $hash{ue};
```