# Perl: Regular Expression

Tags: regex, perl

I have searched for several hours and I've found tons of resources, but I can't seem to put the info together for my purposes.  I have a file with:

```
FirstName LastName
FirstName LastName
FirstName LastName
etc...
```

This is homework assigned to the class by students from their presentation.  99% of the code below is theirs from a template script, I'll comment where my contributions come in.  I'm supposed to find all of the last names that begin with a vowel and output them into a text file.  It seems that I'm having most of my trouble figuring out the regex for "vowel as first character of second field" - as well as some trouble with basic Perl I suppose.  How do I do this?  This isn't really worth much credit at all, but I'm just driving myself crazy trying to figure this out - Thanks a bunch for any help.

```
  #!/usr/bin/perl


  $input = 'names.txt';
  open ($info, $input) or die "Could not open $input";

  $output = 'hw.txt';
  open($fh, '>>', $output) or die "Could not open $output";

  @names = split(/\s/, $line);  #MINE - probably wrong somehow

  while( my $line = <$info>)  {

    if ($names[2] =~ /^AEIOU/){  #MINE - also probably wrong somehow

        print $fh "$line";
      }
  }



  close $info;
  close $fh;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings

Comment: I'm staring at this post, wondering if it is what I think it is or just wishful thinking...more research

Comment: Trying out what is suggested is better than wondering.

Comment: Lol. I meant that I'm researching the topic of "use strict;" and "use warnings;" - It's not entirely apparent to me how to use those yet - Side note though:  Does my problem not lie within my regex?

Comment: regex should be `/^[AEIOU]/i` but this is only part of the problem.

Comment: Jesus.  I tried so many different things... Thank you very much for getting me pointed in the right direction.  The regex was the main factor driving me nuts.  I figured my additions were just gobbledygook.  My first time ever seeing a Perl script was probably an hour ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sound like you have your answer, but just for completeness you're also using `$line` before it's actually initialized, you don't need to re-quote `"$line"` in your print, and also instead of splitting the line first, you could just use a regex match from the very start:

```
while( my $line = <$info> ) {
  if( $line =~ /\s[AEIOU]/ ) {
    print $fh $line;
  }
}
```

That's actually slightly safer than your code too because if there's a double-space then your code will result in the second array element being an `undef` (although there are other ways to mitigate that).

As an aside, I'm very pleased to see Perl still being the subject of homework assignments :)

Comment: I see!  I think that was probably what was intended anyway.  Looks pretty sleek too.  I'll try this out and get back.  Oh yeah, and on the Perl assignment, my professor is a super old fashioned guy who's pretty much been there since the beginning with computers/programming (he said he started with punch cards)...Total genius - came to my college from Carnegie-Mellon.  I guess he knows very close to literally every programming language and has even built several of his own.  He's a walking computer.

Comment: Presto! It worked.  Thank you - My headache is now subsiding.

Comment: ...and just for fun, here's a one-liner from the command line: `perl -ne "print if /\\s[AEIOU]/" names.txt > hw.txt` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Like many programming languages, Perl's array indices start at 0

Comment: Lol, yes indeed.  Well, I changed it to "$names[1]", same result though - the output file is created but left empty...