# How to display the name of the sender's mail when sending a mail using Perl?

Tags: perl, email

I am sending a mail using the following code in Perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$to = 'abcd@gmail.com';
$from = 'webmaster@yourdomain.com'; 
$subject = 'Test Email'; 
$message = 'This is test email sent by Perl Script'; 
open(MAIL, "|/usr/sbin/sendmail -t"); 
# Email Header 
print MAIL "To: $to\n"; 
print MAIL "From: $from\n"; 
print MAIL "Subject: $subject\n\n"; 

# Email Body 
print MAIL $message; 
close(MAIL); 
print "Email Sent Successfully\n";
```

Now how do i get the name  of the sender while i am seeing the name. For eg. when i keep $from as abcd@xyz.com  it displays name as abc while i want to give it my name like James Lawson.?

Comment: You might try `my $from = 'James Lawson <webmaster@yourdomain.com>';`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8023959/725418