# how to combine directory path in perl

Tags: linux, perl

I am having a perl script in which i am giving path to directory as input.
Directory has xml files inside it.

In my code i am iterating through all the xml files and creating absolute path for all xml files. Code is working fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use File::Spec;

$num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($num_args != 1) {
   print "\nUsage: $0 <input directory>\n";
   exit;
}

my $dirPath = $ARGV[0];

opendir(DIR, $dirPath);
my @docs = grep(/\.xml$/,readdir(DIR));

foreach my $file (@docs) 
{
   my $abs_path = join("",$dir,$file);

   print "absolute path is $abs_path";
}
```

Question i have here is, 
joining $dirPath and $file with no separator which means that $dirPath must end in a "/". So is there any way or built in function in perl which take cares of this condition and replaces the join method.

All i want is not to worry about the separator "/". Even if script is called with path as "/test/dir_to_process" or "/test/dir_to_process/", i should be able to produce the correct absolute path to all xml files present without worrying about the separator.

Let me know if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: When you accepted my previous answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28503335/725418) about the same code, I assumed that you understood my comments about the code (which, by the way makes this question redundant). When reading your code now, I see that you did not use *anything* of what I said, not even to use strict and warnings. Was there something you did not understand?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Please* take heed of the advice you are given. It is ridiculous to keep asking questions when comments and answers to previous posts are being ignored.

You *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of *every* Perl program you write, and declare every variable using `my`. It isn't hard to do, and you will be reprimanded if you post code that doesn't have these measures in place.

You `use` the `File::Spec` module in your program but never make use of it. It is often easier to use [`File::Spec::Functions`](https://metacpan.org/module/File::Spec::Functions) instead, which exports the methods provided by `File::Spec` so that there is no need to use the object-oriented call style.

`catfile` will correctly join a file (or directory) name to a path, doing the right thing if path separators are incorrect. This rewrite of your program works fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec::Functions 'catfile';

if (@ARGV != 1) {
   print "\nUsage: $0 <input directory>\n";
   exit;
}

my ($dir_path) = @ARGV;
my $xml_pattern = catfile($dir_path, '*.xml');

while ( my $xml_file = glob($xml_pattern) ) {
   print "Absolute path is $xml_file\n";
}
```

Comment: yes i did took the advice given to me in previous posts. Reason i did not included libraries is because was trying to show only the area of code which needed answer (but from now on i will make sure warning/strict) libraries are always included) . My actual script is bigger and more complicated then what i have shown above. Sorry for confusion. Yes i got the answer and it worked fine using catfile. Thanks for helping

Comment: @user1188611: It is strange to leave out `use strict` but include `#!/usr/bin/perl`! I'm glad you found your answer.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is in the documentation for [File::Spec](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html), e.g., catfile:

```
 $path = File::Spec->catfile( @directories, $filename );
```

or catpath:

```
 $full_path = File::Spec->catpath( $volume, $directory, $file );
```

Answer (score 0):

This will add the trailing slash if not there:

```
$dirPath =~ s!/*$!/!;
```