# How to get array element's value by given key in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm totally new in perl. I want to get element's value by its key from an associative array.
my array is:

```
my %array = a.a.a.a => "my name",
       b.b.b.b => "my home",
       c.c.c.c => "my city";
```

when I print

```
print say %array<b.b.b.b>;
or 
print say %array{b.b.b.b};
```

it shows error, so how can I get this?
code-test link: [codepad link](http://codepad.org/6goCazuy)

Comment: is there any problem in my array?

Comment: You are not using Perl syntax. Also, instead of saying "it shows error", you should *show the error* so we know what it is.

Comment: List of mistakes: 1) You must enclose list in parentheses when assigning to a hash or array, 2) You must (in this case) quote the keys, because `.` is an operator, 3) `print say` is doing the same thing twice. It will also print a `1` (the return value from `say`), 4) Angle braces `<>` are used for globs or file handles, never for hashes.

Comment: @TLP I think OP is writing Perl6 (see my answer), in which case it only has one mistake. If not, then the syntax is wrong, but I would be amazed if these are random mistakes that follow Perl6 rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associate arrays are called [Hash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html) in Perl.

Always use `use strict; use warnings;` in your Perl code. If you use it you will get to know that keys in your hash are not quoted.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
        'a.a.a.a' => "my name",
        'b.b.b.b' => "my home",
        'c.c.c.c' => "my city"
    );
```

To access value of a key you do `$hash{$key}`, so to access b.b.b.b

```
print $hash{'b.b.b.b'};
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/ZYXTiz)

Comment: You are welcome. You may want to read [article on hashes by Gabor](http://perlmaven.com/perl-hashes).

Comment: No need to quote the keys *unless* using strict/warnings.

Comment: It's best practice to `use strict/warnings`. You should read [Why use strict and warnings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings)

Comment: Your answer essentially says "Do X, then fix Y" except doing X caused Y. All the actual problems (hash declaration, hash access, print/say) have no explanation as if they're incidental.

Comment: @RobEarl If you do not quote the keys in this case, it will be considered an expression rather than a string, meaning that `a.a.a.a` will become `aaaa` (4 `a` concatenated by `.`), and you will get a bareword warning. Strict and warnings never cause problems, they only tell you that problems exist.

Comment: @TLP +1 for your detail explanation.

Comment: @TLP So X didn't exactly *cause* Y, but without X or Y the code would've run without error (though differently to intended!). I'm not arguing against strict/warnings, I'm arguing against "quote the hash keys" as a good answer, at least without any further explanation as to why that's required in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote is *almost* valid Perl6, with the only mistake being not quoting the keys. And that is only necessary in this example because `.a` and `.b` look like a method call in Perl6 and will generate undeclared subroutine warnings.

```
my %array =
   'a.a.a.a' => "my name",
   'b.b.b.b' => "my home",  
   'c.c.c.c' => "my city";

say %array<b.b.b.b>;
say %array{'b.b.b.b'};
```

Running this gives what you would expect:

```
$ perl6 hash.pl6
my home
my home
```

This example code looks more like Perl6 than Perl 5 to me, so I thought I would mention this for reference in case you were following a Perl6 tutorial and trying to compile the code with `perl`.

Answer (score 1):

use :

```
my %array = ("a.a.a.a" => "my name",
       "b.b.b.b" => "my home",
       "c.c.c.c" => "my city");

print $array{"b.b.b.b"};
```

Comment: @fatih have changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

use

```
print say $array{"b.b.b.b"};
```

or

```
print "$array{'b.b.b.b'}\n";
```