# Why for loop is not terminating?

Tags: perl

I have input file as following...

```
A0FGR8 659-660 659-662
A4UGR9 728-751
```

And I want output as in two different files(A0FGR8.diso, A4UGR9.diso) and these files suppose to consist the numbers

```
659
660
661
662
```

after this for loop should terminate based on the upper number, but it is not so..
my perl code as follows..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open(F1,"$ARGV[0]") or die;
chomp(@list = <F1>);
close(F1);

for($i = 0; $i <= $#list; $i++) {
    @id=split(/\s+/,$list[$i]);

    open(OUT,">tmp/$id[0].diso") or die;

    for($j = $id[1]; $j = $#id; $j++) {
        ($n1, $n2) = split(/-/, $id[$j]);
        for($k = $n1; $k <= $n2; $k++) {
            print OUT "$k\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Kindly tell me where I have committed mistake and resolve the same.

Comment: `$j=$#id` != `$j==$#id` != `$j<=$#id`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings

Comment: Your loop exit condition on the second loop will always return true, so will never exit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rewrite of your code in saner Perl.  All `for` loops are guaranteed to terminate because I changed them to use the list version of `for` instead of C-style `for`, which is a Good Perl Habit, since list-`for` is a *lot* harder to get wrong.

I also changed the outermost `for` to iterate over the list directly instead of looping over the indexes because you didn't actually use the index for anything other than pulling items out of the list anyhow.

The bare `<>` operator reads from files listed in `@ARGV` (or from `STDIN` if `@ARGV` is empty), so I changed that.  There's rarely a need to explicitly `open $ARGV[0]`.

Finally, I changed the `open` for the output file to use a lexical filehandle and the three-argument form of `open`.  Both are recommended practices.  Lexical filehandles avoid globals and are automatically closed when they go out of scope (...and you forgot to `close` your `OUT`...), while three-arg `open` avoids security bugs when giving it filenames coming from outside the program.

I also made it run cleanly under `strict` and `warnings`, both of which you should *always* `use`.

The revised code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my @list = <>;
chomp @list;

for my $line (@list) {
  my @id = split(/\s+/, $line);

  open my $outfile, '>', "tmp/$id[0].diso"
    or die "Failed to open output file: $!";

  for my $j ($id[1] .. $#id) {
    my ($n1, $n2) = split(/-/, $id[$j]);

    for my $k ($n1 .. $n2) { 
      say $outfile $k;
    } 
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to say whether this will actually work correctly for your data set because you have not provided any sample data to test it against.

Comment: This is just wrong, and the OP *does* provide (minimal) test data so you should have tested it

Answer (score 1):

Your program is much more clearly written like this

You don't say whether you want overlapping ranges to be combined, but your own code makes no attempt to do that so I have left them as they are, so that 659 and 660 are repeated in the output to `A0FGR8.diso`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

while ( <> ) {

    my ($id, @ranges) = split;

    open my $out_fh, '>', "tmp/$id.diso" or die $!;

    for my $range ( @ranges ) {
        my ($start, $end) = split /-/, $range;
        print { $out_fh } "$_\n" for $start .. $end;
    }
}
```

### output

#### `tmp/A0FGR8.diso`

```
659
660
659
660
661
662
```

#### `tmp/A4UGR9.diso`

```
728
729
730
731
732
733
734
735
736
737
738
739
740
741
742
743
744
745
746
747
748
749
750
751
```

### Update

Here's an alternative version that uses the [`Number::Range`](http://metacpan.org/module/Number::Range) module to eliminate duplicate values in overlapping ranges. It isn't a core module, and so it is likely that you will need to install it

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Number::Range;

while ( <DATA> ) {

    my ($id, @ranges) = split;

    my $range = Number::Range->new;

    for my $interval ( @ranges ) {
        no warnings 'Number::Range';
        $range->addrange( $interval =~ s/-/../r ); #/
    }

    open my $out_fh, '>', "$id.diso" or die $!;
    print { $out_fh } "$_\n" for $range->range;
}


__DATA__
A0FGR8 659-660 659-662
```

### output

#### `tmp/A0FGR8.diso`

```
659
660
661
662
```