# Obtaining a value from a nested hash/array data structure

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, data-dumper

I am doing some API queries using Perl and using Data::Dumper to print the contents and hopefully assign several keys as variables.

```
   $client->request( "GET", "interfaces/detail", $opts );
    my $out = decode_json $client->responseContent();
    print Dumper $out;
```

However, I am unable to print a specific key's (b4) output or define it as a variable.

```
print $out{'b4'};
```

I think that this is due to the nested data structure of HASH/ARRAY/HASH/HASH/Key=>Value in JSON format.

```
  DB<1> x $out
0  HASH(0x493f290)
   'data' => ARRAY(0x494e2e0)
      0  HASH(0x4475160)
         'a1' => '11'
         'a2' => '12'
         'a3' => '13'
         'a4' => HASH(0x494e560)
            'b1' => '21'
            'b2' => 22
            'b3' => '23'
            'b4' => '24'
            'b5' => '25'
            'b6' => '26'
            'b7' => '27'
         'a5' => '14'
```

How can I obtain the value "24" from the referenced layout?

Comment: `$out->{data}[0]{a4}{b4}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$out` is not a hash, it is a hash reference.  If you're not sure about references in Perl, read the [Perl Reference Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).  References are dereferenced with `->`.  Instead of `$out{key}` it is `$out->{key}`.

In your specific case you have a hash reference to a list to a hash with another hash.  Dealing with these is covered in the [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).  Since `b4` is several layers down, you need to specify each layer.  `$out->{data}[0]{a4}{b4}`.

---

`$out{key}` is accessing the hash `%out`.  The sigil (ie. `$`, `@` and `%`) changes according to how the variable is being used, but `$out{key}` is still `%out`.

Because `$out{key}` accesses a different variable, you should have gotten an error like `Global symbol "%out" requires explicit package name`.  Unfortunately, Perl doesn't do this by default, you have to turn it on with `use strict`.  This should be one of the first things at the top of your program.  [You should really, really, really use strict and warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings).  It will catch many frustrating mistakes like this one.

Comment: Schwern, this is great help and answers my question.  Thank you!  If I may ask one further question, if I want to iterate through the hash multiple times and obtain value 'B4' from multiple 'A4' hashes, how would I do that?  The below works by statically defining a range of [0..8] but I would like for it to iterate through each hash and grab the 'B4' output programatically.

  for my $slice (0..8) {
  my $out = $out->{data}[$slice]{wwpn};
  print " $out \n";
 }

Comment: @lollan That would be best handled by asking another Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thanks again!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734341/iterating-through-a-hash-of-hashes