# Iterating through an array of hashes

Tags: perl, hash, data-dumper

I have wrote the below routine, to iterate through hashes 0 - 7 and print out the value of a specific key in each.  I need to grab the value of 'b4' in each hash.

I would like to do away with the (0..7), with something smarter for when there are different numbers of hashes.  For instance, sometimes there is only 2 or there may be 160.

```
my $out = decode_json $client->responseContent();

#print "\nOutput is :\n\n" . Dumper $out;
for my $slice (0..7) {
    my $out = $out->{data}[$slice]{b4};
    print " $out \n";
}
```

The data is structured as such:

```
  DB<1> x $out
0  HASH(0x125fb5e0)
   'data' => ARRAY(0x1260d760)
      0  HASH(0x121765d0)
            'b1' => '21'
            'b2' => '22'
            'b3' => '23'
            'b4' => '24'
            'b5' => '25'
            'b6' => '26'
            'b7' => '27'
      1  HASH(0x125fb650)
            'b1' => '21'
            'b2' => '22'
            'b3' => '23'
            'b4' => '24'
            'b5' => '25'
            'b6' => '26'
            'b7' => '27'
      2  HASH(0x1236b960)
            'b1' => '21'
            'b2' => '22'
            'b3' => '23'
            'b4' => '24'
            'b5' => '25'
            'b6' => '26'
            'b7' => '27'
      3  HASH(0x12177030)
            'b1' => '21'
            'b2' => '22'
            'b3' => '23'
            'b4' => '24'
            'b5' => '25'
            'b6' => '26'
            'b7' => '27'
      4  HASH(0x1260da00)
            'b1' => '21'
            'b2' => '22'
            'b3' => '23'
            'b4' => '24'
            'b5' => '25'
            'b6' => '26'
            'b7' => '27'
```

Comment: [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) (the Perl data structures cookbook) might be helpful. It shows how to create and iterate through various data structures, like arrays of hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$out` is a reference to a single-element hash which has an array reference for the value of its `data` element

It's best to extract the reference into a separate variable so that you can access the contents more simply. Suppose you wrote

```
my $data = $out->{data};
```

Thereafter, the array is accessible as `@$data`, the number of elements it contains is `scalar @$data`, and the indices are `0 .. $#$data`. You can access each element of the array with `$data->[0]`, `$data->[1]` etc.

Your code would become

```
my $out  = decode_json $client->responseContent;
my $data = $out->{data};

for my $i ( 0 .. $#$data ) {
    my $item = $data->[$i];
    my $b4 = $item->{b4};
    print "$b4\n";
}
```

But note that, unless you need the array index for other purposes, you are probably better off iterating over the array elements themselves rather than its indices. This code would do the same thing

```
my $out  = decode_json $client->responseContent;
my $data = $out->{data};

for my $item ( @$data ) {
    my $b4 = $item->{b4};
    print "$b4\n";
}
```

Or even just

```
print "$_->{b4}\n" for @$data;
```

if you don't need to do anything else within your loop

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to iterate over the array

```
for my $cur (@{$out->{data}})
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `$out->{data}` is a list reference, not a hash reference.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that originally. Answer fixed.  Note the title is incorrect, which I will correct.

Comment: @mob: There's no such thing as a list reference. `$out->{data}` is an array reference