# How to apply conditions on a output using awk to filter the content

Tags: bash, awk

I want to print all those line in which mp_demand>1
.
I am using awk for this, but somehow not able to achieve that.

```
root@1.2.3.4:#cat a.txt
Target MR 11604 MPG: -1 Region: -1
reading assignments message /a/tmp/a.txt
mpg=1 mrule=11604 reg=33000 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=1
mpg=2 mrule=11604 reg=33000 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=1
mpg=3 mrule=11604 reg=33000 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=1
mpg=4 mrule=11604 reg=33000 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=1
mpg=5 mrule=11604 reg=33000 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=1
mpg=6 mrule=11604 reg=33000 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=34
```

What I am trying is

```
root@1.2.3.4:#  cat a.txt  | awk 'BEGIN {p=0}  $7  >= 0 {p ++} END {print p}' | head 
45877
```

However, the expected output I want is

```
mpg=6 mrule=11604 reg=33000 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=34
```

any other/better ways of doing it?

Comment: I agree it is unfair to down vote a well drafted question like this.

Comment: Maybe disgruntled Perl people for not seeing any Perl? Who knows.

Comment: Or maybe someone thought it's not useful to others.

Comment: @hitman99, your criteria are unclear: did you mean `mp_demand>1` instead?

Comment: @glennjackman , yes I meant mp_demand>1 instead. 
Ed, I fixed the input just now. It was actually truncated initially, as I just posted a part of the text.

Comment: I really do not understand, the need of a down vote here. 
I did my best to craft the question properly.
I tagged perl because, I thought this can be solved by perl one liners as well, hence I asked "if there is a better way to solve this".

Comment: I'm guessing that by not accepting answers to any but one of your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5544515/hitman99) and not responding to some comments from some people trying to help you in those threads you may have ruffled some feathers.

Comment: Hi Ed, Thank you for the clarification. I do not quite understand what you mean by "not accepting answers" but I presume it means , not upvoting them ? I just got voting power recently , and I upvote all the useful answers. But my apologies to anyone who might have been offended, this is a great learning community and did not want anyone to get offended.

Comment: @zdim thanks for tagging me, I didn't know hitman99 had responded. hitman99 - [you knew how to accept an answer last March](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35781963/1745001), I'm just talking about continuing to do the same for other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'=' 'NR>2 && $NF>1' a.txt
mpg=6 mrule=11604 reg=33000 score=10625 rank=0 perc=100 mp_demand=34
```

Comment: thanks that helped :)

Googling it tells me that NF is for the number of fields in the current record, but can you give a brief explanation as to how NF is used here.

Comment: With `-F'='` I've told awk the fields are `=`-separated so the last field, $NF, is the text after the last `=` on the line which is the value you want to test.

Answer (score 2):

With Perl (tagged), using the criterion of `> 1` as the desired output indicates

```
perl -wnE'/mp_demand=([0-9]+)/ && $1 > 1 && print' a.txt
```

Or without the name, `/=([0-9]+)$/`,  *if it's always last in the line* (or you want the last number)

Note: It is generally not needed to `cat` and pipe the file into the command; most tools can feed the file line by line into their `STDIN` when you supply its name after the command (perhaps with `<`)