# perl - short factorial calculator returning long strings of 1's

Tags: perl, loops, syntax, while-loop, factorial

I'm trying to make a program that calculates the factorial of a number. I'm not very familiar with perl, so I think I'm missing some grammar rule.

When I enter 5 the program should return 120. Instead it returns a few dozen 1's. When I try other numbers I still get 1's, but more or less of them depending on if I enter a higher or lower number.

Here's my code:

```
print"enter a positive # more than 0: \n";

$num = <STDIN>;
$fact = 1;

while($num>1)
(
    $fact = $fact x $num;
    $num = $num - 1;
)

print $fact;
system("pause");
```

This is my first post to stack Overflow, so I hope I obeyed all theposting rules.

Comment: Factorial is actually defined for zero (0! = 1), so you should be asking for a non-negative number instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$fact = $fact x $num;
```

[`x`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Multiplicative-Operators) is not the multiplication operator in Perl. It is used to repeat things. `1 x 5` will produce `"11111"`.

Instead you want `*`.

```
$fact = $fact * $num;
```

Which can be written using `*=`.

```
$fact *= $num;
```

---

A few other issues...

[Get used to `strict` and `warnings` now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/ddg#8024241). By default, Perl will let you use variables without declaring them. They are global, which is bad for reasons you'll learn later. Right now it means if you have a typo in a variable name like `$face` Perl won't tell you about it.

Looping over a list of numbers is better done with a `for` loop over a [range using `..`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators).

```
# Loop from 1 to $num setting $factor each time.
for my $factor (1..$num) {
    $fact *= $factor;
}
```

Instead of using a system call to pause the program, use [`sleep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sleep.html).

Comment: pause doesn't do what sleep does, I think: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732683(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: @ysth Yeah. What I really think is going on is Windows has a tendency to immediately close the window upon program termination. I've seen variations on this to prevent that from happening. One is to use `<STDIN>` to wait until the user hits enter.

Comment: also, the original program was completely correct except that it should have said `print length $fact` instead if `print $fact`.  (just kidding)