# How to loop through an array for subset of elements (in reverse order) in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, for-loop

I have an array as below. Need to print the middle elements (element index 5 to element index 0) in reverse order.

```
my @array  = ( 1 .. 10 );
```

**my required output:**

```
5
4
3
2
1
```

I tried below code. But it does not print anything.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
my @array = (1 .. 10);

for $k (5 .. 0){
    print "$array[$k]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that expression `(5 .. 0)` does not return anything, since it means the starting number is greater than the end.

You can run the following code snippet to see the issue (nothing prints out):

```
print for (5 .. 0);
```

For this to do what you want, you would need to use [list operator `reverse`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html):

```
print for (reverse 0 .. 5);
```

Another thing to consider: in Perl, the first element of an array has index `0`. So the list you are looking for is `(0 ..4)` instead of `(0 .. 5)`.

Here is your updated code:

```
my @array = (1 .. 10);
for my $k (reverse 0 .. 4) {
    print "$array[$k]\n";
}
```

Side note: [always `use strict` and `use warnings`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023959/why-use-strict-and-warnings). Under these pragmas, your code would fail Variable `$k` is not declared in the code: it should be `for my $k ...` instead of `for $k ...`.

This can also be expressed in this shorter form:

```
my @array = (1 .. 10);
print "$array[$_]\n" for (reverse 0 .. 4);
```

Side note #2: it is possible to modify the code so it dynamically computes which items should be printed depending on the length of the array. For this, you can use expression `$#array`, which returns the value of the highest index in the array.

Consider:

```
print "$array[$_]\n" for (reverse 0 .. $#array/2);
```

If your array is `(1 .. 11)` (ie has an uneven nombre of elements), this prints:

```
6
5
4
3
2
1
```